# Is finally block will be executed in thread other than main thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        try{        
            System.out.print("1");
            throw new Exception("first");
        }   
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("2");
            throw new Exception("second");      
        }
        **finally**{
            System.out.print("3");
            try{
                System.out.print("4");              
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print("5");
                throw new Exception("third");
            }
            finally{
                System.out.print("6 ");             
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

**Output at first run:**

```
12Exception in thread "main" 346 java.lang.Exception: second
    at src.dec.TST501.main(TST501.java:11)
```

**output at second run:**

```
12346 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: second
    at src.dec.TST501.main(TST501.java:11)
```

output at third run:
1Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: second
2346    at src.dec.TST501.main(TST501.java:11)

Can any one explain me how it is happening?
Is the finally block will be a executed in any other thread than main?

Comment: Actually, I believe the OA's concern is that the text `346` is printed in between the error message in one execution and before the message in another...

Answer (score 9):

The `finally` block is executed on the same thread. The reason the output is interleaved this way has to do with the way standard output and standard error output data.

Standard output is buffered (whereas standard error is not), so how the output is interleaved depends on when the system chooses to flush the output buffer. (Since your terminal emulator simply shows both of these streams together, you get the mixed output you observe.)

Answer (score 1):

It's just because the `System.err` is slower than `System.out`, change to System.err, you will see
`12346 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: second
    at Test.main(Test.java:8)`
 all the time

Answer (score -2):

This is happening because your both finally block will be executed in any circumstances of the execution, whether there comes any exception or not

Comment: that is fine , but in the first run finally block been stated execution after  exception been thrown. In second run finally block started execution before exception been thrown , why it is ?

Comment: Yes, it can not be determined because its printing on console may be differ

Comment: This answer does not explain the different output as reported by the OP ... and that is the *point* of the question.  In short, this doesn't answer the question.